# Stop unknown AppDetectService using port 8000 on windows 10

Tags: windows, iis

I have an unknown AppDetectService using my port 8000 and I am not able to figure out how to close it down or kill any process that seems to be running it. Its being run by System process on PID 4(found that by netstat and searching through task manager). Trying to search for the file running it on task manager leads to ntoskrnl.exe. Also task manager shows it may slightly be using GPU. So my guess is either a system process is holding the port or more probably something is using some kind of system available servers to host a service. Hitting it on the browser shows up this page:
[image]
Netstat results:
[image]

task manager screenshot showing GPU may also be firing:
[image]

Please help me kill this abomination once and for all.

Comment: It depends on what kind of machine you are using. It is a self hosting WCF service which hooks to HTTP service directly, and can be part of a Windows service (in most cases). Go to services panel and stop the suspicious ones.

Comment: I guess I have to go the hard way of trial and error on system services, but atleast now I am more sure thats where I can control it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find out what service was using this port. Since it was impossible to find it even like this, I started to shut down service by service until port 8000 wasn't occupied any more.

In my case, port 8000 was taken over by drivers for **Sound BlasterX AE-5** sound card. Process `Creative.AudPosService` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Creative\Connection Service` has been using this port.

Luckily, it is possible to change this port. Open `Creative.AudPosService.exe.config` and change line where port number is located `<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/"/>` to `<add baseAddress="http://localhost:9999/"/>` or anything else that don't interfere with your work. Restart windows and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, man this was the exact problem. I changed configuration and restarted "Audio Position Service" by Creative and done, my port problems are a thing of the past now.

Comment: Did you manage to shut it down completely or just change port? If you have shut it down, did it in any way harm the way we use these audio drivers or software for it? I have no idea for what is this service used for. I wrote to technical support and I'm still waiting for their answer. My guess is that that "Scout" feature is using it to communicate with mobile app, but I am not sure since I don't intend to use it.

Comment: As I suspected, it was for "Scout" service. Their response:  `With regard to your inquiry about the "Creative.AudPosService" located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Creative\Connection Service\"; this is generally for Scout Radar purposes.

We regret to inform you that we do not support customer(s) who modifies the original driver layout. We are not liable for any software/driver malfunction for any modification.`

Comment: I changed the port and restarted service as I didn't know where creative used that. I don't like music enhancers and usually disable them anyway. So I don't use that feature. Nice of you to clarify that from creative people. I change ports on my services left and right so its strange for them to shrug off on a mere port change. Looks like messed up configs on their part. They should atleast use ports with higher value I think or some peculiar number to not conflict with ports popular among developers in the 3000-10000 range.

Comment: Maybe it would be good that you ask them, as I did, to enable users to change that port in their "Sound Blaster Connect" application. This seems logical. They took my suggestion into consideration, but more people asking for this will increase chance for this to be included in one of the next versions of their drivers.